# Custom WebView / WebViewX like iFrame flutter mobile or WebView in a rectangle

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a mobile app in flutter where I can display the content from a webView but i need it in a rectangular form and inside a widget in the center of the app.